# HTML button isn't working with JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have defined a function in javascript and referenced it in my HTML in the form of a button but when I click the button, the function doesn't run. There is also an error in the console saying the function I'm using is defined but it isn't used. Can anyone help or maybe explain what is going on? Sorry if I don't make sense sometimes, I am a beginner to JavaScript and HTML, hence the very simple scripts below.

I double-checked my code and checked for typos and everything looks fine to me, here is the code:

Javascript Code:

```
function displayDate() {
  document.getElementById("now").innerHTML = Date();
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DateCheckerThing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">What is today's date?</button>
    <h1 id="now"></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "defined but isn't used" isn't an error that a browser would report. It's something an IDE would tell you when you're writing the code, not when you click.

Comment: Is the JS in an external file? Are you loading the file with a `<script>` tag?

Comment: @Barmar yeah, I should've cleared that up, I'm using CodeSandbox and the console gives me that error. Also, I am not using a script tag in my HTML.

Comment: What do you mean it's not external? @WesleyHall It's not in the HTML file so it must be in a JS file which is external to the HTML file, right?

Comment: @Andy my bad, it is external

Comment: const date = new Date().  document.getElementById("now").innerHTML = date;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's clarify something: Your function *is* being used, but just not in the way that your text editor or IDE expects. Your HTML code is calling the function whenever a button is pressed, and your code *does* work as intended. *However*, your text editor/IDE is noticing that the function isn't being used by any other Javascript code; Thus, you're getting a **warning** that no other **Javascript** is using the function. Your text editor/IDE doesn't know that the HTML file is actually using the function. This won't actually result in any **errors**.

Another issue that I notice is that you don't have a script tag in your HTML code. To fix this, you can add `<script defer src="js_file_name">` to your HTML (obviously, change the string to match the name of your JS file). This loads the JS file along with your HTML, so that functions will be loaded from the JS file. (Note: the `defer` keyword just means that the JS file will be loaded *after* the HTML page is loaded.)

Comment: Oh, thanks! The only thing is that I don't see the date pop up on my h1 tag, is it because the date function doesn't work anymore for javascript?

Comment: @WesleyHall I edited my answer to provide a solution as for why the h1 tag isn't updating.

Comment: Thanks @dvub you helped me a lot, I'm a beginner to javascript and web dev in general so I might get lots of things wrong but you helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: @WesleyHall No problem! If you ever are confused on something or need help, don't hesitate to ask for help! Don't give up and have fun on your journey :)